# Best strategy to phase out InfoPath forms in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

My client uses InfoPath form libraries. They want to phase out the use of InfoPath all together and replace it some alternative.

My idea is to implement custom forms for the same and host it within SharePoint, so that the users can have a web based alternative, in place of client application such InfoPath Form Filler.

What can be the best strategy to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure they want to use browser forms, I'd start by investigating Forms9 and Nintex. I think Qdabra did a webinar on getting your data out of your existing InfoPath forms.

However it might be smart not to rush, since InfoPath is not disappearing for several years. New options are in the works. Microsoft is working on native solutions such as Forms On SharePoint Lists that might meet your client's needs in a year or two. Also Formotus (my company) has app-based form filling solutions and has announced the intent to continue superseding InfoPath, so the right solution may come from there too.

Recommended reading: My blog series on InfoPath Alternatives

http://www.formotus.com/category/infopath-alternatives

Comment: Can you please provide the link to the Qdabra webinar?